# Difficult GUI for the native OpenGL ES redererer

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I need to write a simple model editor. But it will require a difficult GUI including GUI in the world space.
So, I think it's a very bad idea to draw GUI over a C++ render in Java. But OpenGL has very low-level for this purpose.
I think it has some solutions already. But I can't find.
Who knows some native GUI libraries for Android GL ES? Or maybe I need to think in another way.

Comment: Just throwing in a curveball. How about Qt Android

Comment: It hasn't a free commercial license,unfortunetaly, as I know.

Comment: @Laser, sorry, I bad know English... `Just throwing in a curveball.` Is it mean a `difficult problem`?